# how to set Default time zone and date format

Tags: users

I have user registration page in that I could see Time Zone as in screen shot attached now problem is I want to make it as default time  zone for all users as well Need to use same date format throughout drupal7 i,e in content type **views** also, can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Please attach screenshot as mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set default timezone and whether user should be able to edit default timezone settings or not.

Go to **Regional and language settings**:

http://yousite.com/admin/config/regional/settings

And ***uncheck* : *Users may set their own time zone.***

On same page other settings also available. See :

[image]

To add any new format you can add from here :

http://yousite.com/admin/config/regional/date-time

Comment: @No Sssweat: yea added the format...now how can i implement in my content view?

Comment: You should be able to locate newly created format in field formatter  in view. If it is a date field it should say : Choose how users view dates and times.

Comment: @No Sssweat, Purpose is to use same date format across the site. It would be hard to maintain specific date format if they are added in view directly. Better would be to create custom format from date-time settings and use that.

Comment: @yukika, When you add the date field to your view, for Date Format, select the date format you just added.

Comment: @NoSssweat: yes after adding the format i will select the format.yes it works as u said